# How much space do i need for "preserve files across reboots"?

Tags: 16.04, usb, unetbootin

I'm using Unetbootin to download a USB boot drive and I'm not sure how much space to preserve. I'm not even sure if I need any.

[image]

Comment: As much as possible unless you know that you need drive space for some other purpose. See the answer by @C.S.Cameron

Answer (score 3):

Minimum persistence for a casper-rw file is 1MB*.

Maximum persistence for a casper-rw file is 4GB**.

Maximum persistence for a casper-rw partition is only limited by disk size, but does not seem to be working for UNetbootin, (or other syslinux installs), with 16.04 64bit or later, [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) works for this.

*Note that if the persistence file is too small, and it gets filled up, the drive will no longer boot.

**This is maximum size for a FAT32 file.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your needs.

- If you are going to use the live usb for booting many times than you need to preserve space depending on how many files you need to store. e.g. if you do not want to install Ubuntu and need it temporarily and would run it using "Try Ubuntu without installing" option multiple times.
- If you need the Usb to install Ubuntu, then you do not need to reserve any space. e.g. if you need the Usb to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Whats the difference between a live boot and just using the USB?

Comment: There is no difference. :)

Comment: Oh man this makes no sense.

Comment: So what are the circumstances where someone would use space and where someone wouldn't?

Comment: Edited the answer, hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

If you only plan to use the USB to boot Ubuntu or to install Ubuntu, you do not need to add any extra space.

The extra space is only useful if you need to install programs to the USB environment once you have started the live session, or if you plan to create application data that you wish to preserve.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. Anywhere between one and four gigs, the default settings, will work perfectly. Ubuntu stores all files you create or download in one big encrypted file called casper, that only it can read. It wants to know how big you want casper to be. If you set casper to 2 gigs, it'll store up to 2 gigs of your files. It's also nice to keep a few gigs free so casper doesn't take up the whole stick, so that you can also store regular files on it. If you're using a 16G thumbdrive or bigger, set it to max. Otherwise, you'll find your personal preference somewhere between 1 gig and the size of your stick.