# How To Keep My Files After Rebooting?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, google-chrome

I Wanted To Use Ubuntu From USB So I Burned The Iso File By Using "Rufus.exe",,

It Worked Fantastic! But There Is a Problem Which Is, If I Installed Google Chrome Browser For Example, I Can't Find It The Next Time I Boot From The Usb!

So How To Keep Everything I Install For The Next Time I Boot From That USB? Is That Possible Or I Have To Install Ubuntu Side By Side With Windows To Do It ??

Comment: The duplicated page does not mention Full install to USB, a Full install is like an install to internal HDD and has many advantages over Persistent install, faster boot, more secure, can use proprietary drivers, for further comparison see http://askubuntu.com/questions/156026/difference-between-livecd-liveusb-full-install-and-persistence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a Live USB Boot Drive with persistence enabled.
See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)

Comment: space used to preserve files across reboots(ubuntu only) ,, what should i enter this value and what does it  mean ??

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/811261/how-much-space-do-i-need-for-preserve-files-across-reboots

Comment: No problem ^.^ Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can dual boot it ubuntu and windows. Just create a partition in your C:/ drive say 60-100 GB, and go through the install like that. Make sure you install to the empty partition. Depending on whether or not Linux is being nice, (I've always had an issue like the following) you might have to switch bios boot modes when swapping. Plenty of YouTube videos out there to help you dual boot ubuntu. It's been done before can be done again.

Comment: its a good idea ! but i need to boot from this usb from many devices !

Comment: You can have ONE computer installed with Linux, and install the Linux version of TeamViewer. What I did was set up a TeamViewer account, and I could access my Linux computer and operate it fully through a windows computer. That way you wouldn't have to boot off USB all the time.

Comment: You have to sign into the same profile on both computers so you don't need to be at the Linux to login.

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer?  Providing a step by step guide would be ideal.  It may help others in the future.